# Java 6 ScriptEngine and JSON.parse problem

Tags: java, javascript, json, rhino

The Rhino release that is included in Java 6 ScriptEngine does not have a JSON parser.  I've tried including crockfords `JSON2.js` in my script on the `scriptengine.eval()`.  When I try to do the `JSON.parse`, it ends up giving me a script error that `.replace` is an unknown function. `.replace` is referenced several places in JSON2, and it works fine inside a browser (IE7, IE8, FF3).  Anyone see this and have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for loooking at this.  I solved it.  Pilot Error.  Simply put, the string I was passing to JSON.parse was *not* a correct JSON string.  It was a java object toString().  So, the error message was unhelpful, but I was giving bad content.