# Is there "native" support for JSON in JDK6 Script Engine?

Tags: java, json, rhino

I'm using JDK6the standard  Scripting.  I need to store and retrieve some JavaScript Objects that also contain Java Objects to JSON.  I loaded the json2.js into the ScriptENgine and can use it fine without issue if the objects are all created in the Scrip Engine.  The moment I try to use my own Java classes, I get some errors like "object does not support toJSON" errors.

I did not find much about JSON in Java Scripting / Rhino context.

Am I doing something totally wrong?  What's the best way of achieving the requirement?

Comment: This is saying roughly the same thing (use JSON2):
[Java 6 + JSON2.parse()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405410/java-6-scriptengine-and-json-parse-problem)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, rhino does not contain a built-in JSON serialization capability.

The errors you're seeing are probably because json2.js uses the statement `typeof value.toJSON` to determine of the object in question implements its own serialization function.  On JavaScript objects, failed property lookups return `undefined`.  On Java objects, failed member lookups throw exceptions.

One approach to solving this problem would be to modify json2 such that as it traverses an object structure:

1. it checks whether each value in question extends from the JavaScript base `Object` prototype or the Java `Object` base class, and
2. applies different encoding logic for Java and JavaScript object instances.

I don't know if anyone has already tackled the problem of serializing an arbitrary Java object to JSON via reflection.  If so, then this might be a good use of it.

Hope this helps!